# Changing Entry Point of x64 application produces no reloc table

Tags: visual-c++, linker, portable-executable, relocation

I have created a simple application, and wanted to minimize size.

The app looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:testfc")


#pragma check_stack(off)
#pragma runtime_checks("su",off) 

int testfc()
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "test", "test", 0);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "main", "main", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

With the `#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:testfc")` i can see that linker doesn't produce any relocs, the option `/DYNAMICBASE` is enabled in linker, so this is weird. Hovewer if i remove `#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:testfc")` and return to the original entry point, the relocs gets produced. How can i change the entry point but keep relocation table? This is only happens in x64 build, with x86 i have no such problems.

Answer (score 2):

relocation's absolute not depend from entry point. if linker doesn't produce any relocs - this mean only that no actual relocation`s in your code - nothing to produce.

when you use `#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:testfc")` your code is tiny - only `int testfc()` and all (and you forget call `ExitProcess` in it - this is error). string `"test"` is produce relocs in x86 code because here used absolute address for string. but x64 use rip-addressing. so here really no relocs.

when you comment `#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:testfc")` situation is serious changed. linker by default use `mainCRTStartup` as [entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol). as result CRT code is linked. the `mainCRTStartup` (which call your `main`) have some relocations already